# Distance between two numbers in looping sequence

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

Assuming you have a sequence like this: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, etc. Basically a sequence consisting of N numbers, repeating over and over.

What is the simplest algorithm for finding the distance/difference between two numbers in this sequence? For example the distance `from 5 to 7 is +2` and the distance `from 0 to 6 is -2`. For a more high level view what I have a looping/repeating sequence number, and I need to find out how much "before" or "after" a number is of another on the closest path (fewest number between them).

Comment: What have you tried.  Iterate when you find the number1 keep iterating with a distance counter.  If you find number2 then you have a distance.  If you find number1 then reset the distance counter.  Save the smallest distance counter.  For the - just switch the two numbers.

Comment: I'm looking for fast way, the best way I've come up with is this: `n = (from + size) - to; if n > size/2 then n -= size` But it involves one branch

Comment: are the numbers always contiguous? I've just realised I looked at an answer to a much more complicated problem

Comment: Here's a related question (implementation in JS) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797186/distance-between-two-numbers-in-looping-numerical-sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming X>Y:

```
dist(X, Y) = min { X-Y, N-(X-Y-1) }
```

Examples for N = 7:

dist(7, 5) = min {7-5, 7-(7-5-1)} = min {2, 6} = 2

dist(6, 0) = min {6-0, 7-(6-0-1)} = min {6, 2} = 2

dist(5, 1) = min {5-1, 7-(5-1-1)} = min {4, 4} = 4

The last example points a small flaw in your distance definition: Is dist(5, 1) = 4 or dist(5, 1) = -4 ? I've changed your definition a little bit to avoid negative distances (so my algorithm calculates the absolute value of the distance). If you want to keep your definition then make the distance negative if and only if the first argument of the `min` is greater than the second.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple and work with consecutive and non consecutive numbers, maybe make it an extension method :

```
[TestFixture]
public class NumbersFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void FindDistance()
    {
        var numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2 };

        var num1 = 6;
        var num2 = 0;

        var from = numbers.IndexOf(num1);
        var indexFound = numbers.FindIndex(from, f => f == num2);
        var distance = from - indexFound;

        var result = string.Format("{0}", distance);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```