# Distance between two numbers in looping numerical sequence

Tags: javascript

I want to find the shortest distance between two numbers in looping sequence, e.g. 0 to 6:

```
... 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ...
```

In also need to know which "way" is shorter (to the left or to the right).

So, if my two numbers are 0 and 6, the shortest distance is 1 by counting backwards (to the left).

The following function works, but only if `next` is greater than `crt`.

```
var MAX_NUMBER = 6; // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6   0 1 2 3 4 5 6   0 1 2 3 4 5 6

function shorterDirection(crt, next) {
  var toRight = next - crt;
  var toLeft = MAX_NUMBER - (next - crt - 1);

  return toLeft < toRight ? 'left' : 'right';
}

console.log(shorterDirection(0, 6));
```

I can't figure out how to make it work both ways. For example, if I use `shorterDirection(4, 3)`, I want the function to return `left`.

Comment: This ought to lead you in the right direction: [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

Comment: Are the numbers always going to in sequence?

Comment: @putvande Yes, but the max number could change, so it should also work with for example (0 - 5): `... 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 1 2 3 4 5 ...`

Comment: And what if you have 0 - 5 and you want to calculate from 2 - 5.. thats equal in both directions.

Comment: @putvande If there is a tie, it could be either `left` or `right` (doesn't matter).

Comment: @MikeC I tried that, but I don't know where to use it in this case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
function shorterDirection(crt, next) {
  var toRight = (next + MAX_NUMBER+1 - crt) % (MAX_NUMBER+1);
  return toRight > (MAX_NUMBER+1) / 2 ? 'left' : 'right';
}
```

Note that there can be ties. In that case the above will return `left`, even though `right` would be just as good.

As you can see there is a lot of `MAX_NUMBER+1` in there. It would be more suitable if you would have a constant `NUMBER_COUNT`, which would be one greater than the `MAX_NUMBER` you have now.

#### How it works

You would start by writing this:

```
var toRight = next - crt;
```

But that goes "wrong" when *next* is less than *crt* -- you get a negative number. To solve that you would add `MAX_NUMBER+1`:

```
var toRight = next + NUMBER+1 - crt;
```

... but now you get a too large number when *next* is greater than *crt*. That you can solve by subtracting as many `NUMBER+1` as necessary to get within the range *0...MAX_NUMBER*. That is what the modulo (`%`) operator does. So you get:

```
var toRight = (next + MAX_NUMBER+1 - crt) % (MAX_NUMBER+1);
```

Once you have that result, you can reason that if it takes more than half of the numbers to go to the right, you better go to the left (which will be less than half of the numbers). This is encoded as:

```
return toRight > (MAX_NUMBER+1) / 2 ? 'left' : 'right';
```

Comment: Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @trincot Thanks, also for the great explanation. That works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Your notation is wrong. You are using [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) in `Z/7Z`.

The parameter should be `7`, not `6`.

I would get the distance in one direction and the other and compare:

```
var modulus = 7; /* Z/7Z */
function shorterDirection(crt, next) {
  var toRight = (next - crt + modulus) % modulus;
  var toLeft = (crt - next + modulus) % modulus;
  return toLeft < toRight ? 'left' : 'right';
}
```

The code above assumes both arguments belong to `{0, ..., modulus-1}`. If you want to allow wider ranges, e.g. `{modulus+1, ..., modulus-1}`, the proper way to calculate the distances is

```
((next - crt) % modulus + modulus) % modulus;
((crt - next) % modulus + modulus) % modulus;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a similar solution that the one in the accepted answer (which was written slightly earlier). But now I also know why to use 7 (+1) and not 6!